# SWIFTUI and Core Motion

Tags: swiftui, core-motion

I am trying to display the accelerometer data in a SWIFTUI view. This code works to print to the console, but I can't understand how to get it inside a view so I can use it in SWIFTUI.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion


struct AccelerometerView: View {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()


    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text("accelerate:").onAppear {
                print("ON APPEAR")
                self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude

                    print("pitch: \(attitude.pitch)")
                    print("yaw: \(attitude.yaw)")
                    print("roll: \(attitude.roll)")
                }
            }//.onappear

            //Text("Pitch:\(attitude.pitch)")

        }//Vstack

    }//view
}//struct

struct AccelerometerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AccelerometerView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
struct AccelerometerView: View {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()

    @State private var pitch = Double.zero
    @State private var yaw = Double.zero
    @State private var roll = Double.zero

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text("Pitch: \(pitch)")
            Text("Yaw: \(yaw)")
            Text("Roll: \(roll)")
        }//Vstack
        .onAppear {
                print("ON APPEAR")
                self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude

                    print("pitch: \(attitude.pitch)")
                    print("yaw: \(attitude.yaw)")
                    print("roll: \(attitude.roll)")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.pitch = attitude.pitch
                        self.yaw = attitude.yaw
                        self.roll = attitude.roll
                    }
                }
            }//.onappear
    }//view
}//struct
```

Comment: That works!  Can you explain for me how the DispatchQueue works?  Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: Dispatch Queue is an object to manage the execution serially or concurrently on your app's main thread or on a background thread. In this case the callback of CoreMotion is a background thread so you need to update the vars in the main thread (the UI updates always must have done in the main thread)

Comment: This answer is flawed - because `AccelerometerView` is constantly reinitialized, the `CMMotionManager` object is constantly recreated. It would be better to turn it into `@State var` to avoid recreation. Also onAppear could lead to duplicate calls.